# Laplace pairs - proof of summation transform

Tags: calculus, summation, laplace-transform

I am studying this question for my finals revision and I'm lost on how to start it, can anyone suggest something? Probably pretty simple but I've hit a dead end.

Here's the question:

If $F_i(t)$ and $f_i(s)$ are Laplace pairs, show that:

$$\mathcal L\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n F_i(t)\right\} = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathcal L\left\{F_i\right\}= \sum_{i=1}^n f_i(s)$$

Just need to be pointed in the right direction for the proof. Thank you for your time for reading this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes from the linearity of the integral
\begin{align}
\mathcal L\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n F_i(t)\right\} &=\int_0^\infty\left(\sum_{i=1}^n F_i(t)\right)\mathrm e^{st}\mathrm d t\\
&=\int_0^\infty\left(F_1(t)+\cdots+F_n(t)\right)\mathrm e^{st}\mathrm d t\\
&=\int_0^\infty F_1(t)\mathrm e^{st}\mathrm d t+\cdots+\int_0^\infty F_n(t)\mathrm e^{st}\mathrm d t\\
&=\mathcal L\left\{F_1(t)\right\}+\cdots+\mathcal L\left\{ F_n(t)\right\}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\mathcal L\left\{F_i(t)\right\}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(s)
\end{align}